# Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [Java SE 6 [1.6.0_65-b14-462]]' in project

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I am trying to run an existing Java project in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), and I am very new to Java and Eclipse, so I am unable to figure out why this error is coming in the project.

Here is the complete error:

> > **Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
> >     Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [Java SE 6 [1.6.0_65-b14-462]]' in project 'INFO 2413 Server'    INFO 2413 Server        Build path    Build Path Problem**

Comment: I had a similar issue, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083461/unbound-classpath-container-in-eclipse fixed it in my case.

Answer (score 11):

1. Make sure you have JDK 1.6 installed on your machine and set up in Eclipse. Go to menu *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Installed JREs*. If you don't see it, use the "Add" button to point it to your installation directory.
2. **Right click the project -> *Properties* -> *Java Build Path*.
3. You should see something like "JRE System Library [Java SE 6 [1.6.0_65-b14-462]] (unbound)". Select this, click edit, and set it to an installed JRE 1.6. Either "Alternate JRE" or "Workspace Default" should work depending on how your Eclipse is configured. You can also try removing the library and re-adding it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go into menu *File* -> *Import* -> *Existing project* into  *library* -> and select the path to your project.